# Wrong position reported by solvePnP

Tags: c++, opencv

I rendered an image in a simple OpenGL app with a chess board in it at position     `[0, 0, 6000]` and rotation `[1.30245, 0.0, 0.0]`. I tried detecting corners of the chessboard an even exporting all the positions of chessboard cell corners (they are the same as detected by `findChessboardCorners`) using OpenCV, but the result returned by `solvePnP` is tvec: `[-1010, -464.251, 11475.2]` rvec: `[-1.08368, -4.33719e-07, -2.28698e-07]` which is totally wrong especially Z coordinate, which is more than 10 times larger than the real one. [image]
The screen coordinates of the corners (from top left) are:

```
[630.613, 452.667;
 740.409, 452.667;
 850.204, 452.667;
 960, 452.667;
 1069.8, 452.667;
 1179.59, 452.667;
 1289.39, 452.667;
 618.819, 479.693;
 732.546, 479.693;
 846.273, 479.693;
 960, 479.693;
 1073.73, 479.693;
 1187.45, 479.693;
 1301.18, 479.693;
 606.148, 508.727;
 724.099, 508.727;
 842.049, 508.727;
 960, 508.727;
 1077.95, 508.727;
 1195.9, 508.727;
 1313.85, 508.727;
 592.501, 540;
 715.001, 540;
 837.5, 540;
 960, 540;
 1082.5, 540;
 1205, 540;
 1327.5, 540;
 577.759, 573.782;
 705.172, 573.782;
 832.586, 573.782;
 960, 573.782;
 1087.41, 573.782;
 1214.83, 573.782;
 1342.24, 573.782;
 561.784, 610.388;
 694.523, 610.388;
 827.261, 610.388;
 960, 610.388;
 1092.74, 610.388;
 1225.48, 610.388;
 1358.22, 610.388;
 544.416, 650.187;
 682.944, 650.187;
 821.472, 650.187;
 960, 650.187;
 1098.53, 650.187;
 1237.06, 650.187;
 1375.58, 650.187]
```

The image of the chessboard:
[image]

The corner points of the chessboard:

```
[290, 290, 0;
 530, 290, 0;
 770, 290, 0;
 1010, 290, 0;
 1250, 290, 0;
 1490, 290, 0;
 1730, 290, 0;
 290, 530, 0;
 530, 530, 0;
 770, 530, 0;
 1010, 530, 0;
 1250, 530, 0;
 1490, 530, 0;
 1730, 530, 0;
 290, 770, 0;
 530, 770, 0;
 770, 770, 0;
 1010, 770, 0;
 1250, 770, 0;
 1490, 770, 0;
 1730, 770, 0;
 290, 1010, 0;
 530, 1010, 0;
 770, 1010, 0;
 1010, 1010, 0;
 1250, 1010, 0;
 1490, 1010, 0;
 1730, 1010, 0;
 290, 1250, 0;
 530, 1250, 0;
 770, 1250, 0;
 1010, 1250, 0;
 1250, 1250, 0;
 1490, 1250, 0;
 1730, 1250, 0;
 290, 1490, 0;
 530, 1490, 0;
 770, 1490, 0;
 1010, 1490, 0;
 1250, 1490, 0;
 1490, 1490, 0;
 1730, 1490, 0;
 290, 1730, 0;
 530, 1730, 0;
 770, 1730, 0;
 1010, 1730, 0;
 1250, 1730, 0;
 1490, 1730, 0;
 1730, 1730, 0]
```

The FOV angle of the camera is 20 degrees (with no distortion). I calculate the camera matrix and use solvePnP as follows:

```cpp
std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners{...}; // coordinates of the corners in the screenshot
std::vector<cv::Point3f> cornerPoints{...}; // coordinates of the corners in the image of the chessboard

const double w = 1920.0;
const double h = 1080.0;
const auto focalLengthX = (w / 2.0) / std::tan(fieldOfView / 2.0);
const auto focalLengthY = (h / 2.0) / std::tan(fieldOfView / 2.0);
const cv::Mat cameraMatrix = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
                              focalLengthX, 0, w/2,
                              0, focalLengthY, h/2,
                              0, 0,   1);
cv::Vec3d rvec;
cv::Vec3d tvec;
const cv::Mat distortion = cv::Mat::zeros(5, 1, CV_32FC1);
const bool ret = cv::solvePnP(cornerPoints, corners, cameraMatrix, distortion,
                              rvec, tvec, false, cv::SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE);
```

I tried all the algorithms and they all return a similar result. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How did you find the intrinsics (cameramatrix)? Is that one identical to the camera matrix in openGL?

Comment: Is the value of "corners" identical to the object points in 3D (object centered 3D points)? What's the 3D size of the quad?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the 3D coordinate systems in openCV and openGL have different axis orders/directions.

Comment: your focal length calculations are wrong. if you have square pixels, fx = fy. yours aren't. **which way** is the FoV? horizontal, vertical, diagonal?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you! Your question helped a lot. It was horizontal FOV (Y axis). I fixed my camera matrix and now solvePnP returns the correct position and rotation.

Comment: just to review: opencv's coordinate systems are right-handed, X right, Y down, Z far (camera/screen). when you say horizontal, that means along the X axis, i.e. width.